# Java Generic how to cast to sub type to call generic method

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have following interface:

```
public interface EntityCloneService<T extends AbstractNamedEntityBase> {

 /**
  * Given a UUID load the Entity Type.
  * 
  * @param uuid
  * @return  Entity From DB and 
  */
 public T getByUuid(UUID uuid);


 /**
  * Given the Existing Entity,  clone it and save in DB, then return clone instance.
  */
 public T getCloneAndSave(T existingEntity) throws Exception;

}
```

Now I have Generic Service, where I have

```
@Component
public class GenericEntityCloneService {

    private static final Map<String,EntityCloneService<? extends AbstractNamedEntityBase>> registration = 
            new HashMap<String,EntityCloneService<? extends AbstractNamedEntityBase>>(); // here we have registration of all entity by name to service actual implementation.

    public void clone(AbstractNamedEntityBase existingEntity) {
        EntityCloneService<? extends AbstractNamedEntityBase> service = registration.get("SOME KEY");
        AbstractNamedEntityBase  entity =   service.getByUuid(ref.getUuid());  // THIS WORKS because it up casting.

        service.getCloneAndSave(entity);    // now how do I pass entity object such that 
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this code does not compile. I know that getCloneAndSave() I am passing the type AbstractNamedEntityBase which is not allowed.  So how do I make a call service.getCloneAndSave(entity); Any help is greatly appreciated.  I am using java 8.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: Since you don’t know the actual type argument of the particular `EntityCloneService` implementation at this point, it is impossible to do that in a type safe way.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using the `T` as both producer and consumer hence you can't use bounded type parameters here. You have to use method level generics instead like so,

```
public <S> S getCloneAndSave(S existingEntity) throws Exception;
```

Comment: This will compile, but an EntityCloneService is supposed to work with T instances, not just any possible type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
AbstractNamedEntityBase entity = service.getByUuid(ref.getUuid());
```

That line discards `T`.  Each EntityCloneService works with exactly one subclass of AbstractNamedEntityBase.  The service’s getCloneAndSave method requires an object of type `T`, which is *some specific subclass* of AbstractNamedEntityBase.

There is no way to preserve the generic type of a value in your Map.  All you will ever know about it is that it’s an `EntityCloneService<? extends AbstractNamedEntityBase>`.  However, you have some options to work around it.

The easiest is to add a default method inside EntityCloneService.  Inside that interface, `T` is known, and there is no need to refer to AbstractNamedEntityBase directly:

```
default T getCloneAndSaveFor(UUID uuid)
throws Exception {
    T entity = getByUuid(uuid);
    return getCloneAndSave(entity);
}
```

Another possibility is writing a separate method in GenericEntityCloneService, which knows each EntityCloneService has a specific type, even if that specific type is not itself known:

```
private <E extends AbstractNamedEntityBase> E getCloneAndSaveFor(
    UUID uuid,
    EntityCloneService<E> service)
throws Exception {

    E entity = service.getByUuid(uuid);
    return service.getCloneAndSave(entity);
}
```

Side notes:

- `throws Exception` is not a good practice.  Don’t force callers to catch unchecked exceptions which are intended to expose programmer errors, like NullPointerException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, IllegalArgumentException, etc.
- You can shorten your Map declaration to `private static final Map<String,EntityCloneService<? extends AbstractNamedEntityBase>> registration = new HashMap<>();`.